# getting null as a response, but data is inserting in database

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, pdo

So, I'm working on some project (basically exploring jquery and pdo).

I'm getting NULL when i dump query, but the data is actually inserted in database after submiting, i would like if someone can explain why is this happening.

The main part i didn't want a blank response is because i wanted to show the message after successful query ( `success: function(data) { if(data){//...} }` )

---

Starting from here, this is my insert method:

```
  public function insert($sql, $params) {
            $sq = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO ".$sql);
            $res = $sq->execute($params);
           //var_dump ($res) is giving true here
            if(!$res){
                die("error");
            }
        }
```

Input:

```
<form id="add_student" method="POST"> 
<input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="First name" pattern="[A-Za-z]{2,}" required>
<input type="submit" value="Add">
</form>
```

Jquery:

```
$("#add_student").submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
fname    = $("#fname").val();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost/pdo/add.php",
    data: {fname:fname},
        cache : false,
        success: function(data) {
            if(data){
                $("#alert-message-success").removeClass("hiddenAlert").html("Record added to database.").delay(7000).fadeOut(5000);
            }
    },
        error: function() {
        $("#alert-message-error").removeClass("hiddenAlert").html("There was an error insertin record to database.").delay(7000).fadeOut(5000);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Insert php file:

```
$db = new Database();

if(isset($_POST['fname'])) {
    $sql = "students (name) VALUES (?)";
    $name = $_POST['fname'];

    $params = [$name];

    $res = $db->insert($sql, $params);
    var_dump($res); // this is NULL

    if(!$res){
        var_dump($res); //This is also NULL
    }
}
```

[image: response from add.php]

its 2 NULL's because they are dumped.

Is it NULL because it is prepared statement or is it something else? I'm new into the PDO and JQuery so i would like if someone could answer.

Comment: You aren't returning anything in your function..

Comment: `$_POST['fname']` is put into `$name` and then your referencing `$fname`.

Comment: Yea, devon was right, i wasn't returning anything, but that's weird to me cause results were actually inserted in database.

Comment: @NigelRen i modified code for this question because code was too long, original is good.

Comment: @Devon thank you sir.

Comment: inserting data was successful but insert function is not returning anything. try to wrap it like this.
try {
    $db->insert($sql, $params);
    return 'inserted';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}

Comment: @kojaa the execution of the query would still be performed regardless of the return value

Comment: @GianTomakin i changed insert method to return me $res, now everything is good, but thanks for your help anyways sir.

Comment: @Devon yea i understand that, but i was confused why is it NULL , until you said i need to return something, i get it now :D